70s-80s animation with an island of robots
I'm looking to identify an old animation with an island of robots. My guess is that it's stop-motion animation because I remember it being peculiar. My subconscious is oscillating between "cartoon" and "3D animation."
At the end of the '70s, but it might have been 1980 or 1981 (not later because I travelled from Brazil), there was this cartoon/animation where a boy inherits (I think) an island where his uncle (I think) constructed robots. As a matter of fact, the blonde (I think) girl who receives him is a robot too.
Somehow along the line, a big ape—also a robot—is defeated, the girl is saved, and in the final scene they are going home in a canoe. The boy glitches and keeps repeating the same word (like a broken record, if people still know what records are). I don't remember what it was (sorry, it was almost half a century ago), but it could have been "now we're going home... home... home... home..."
I've been trying to find it "for some time" now. Oh yeah, I watched it in Brazil, dubbed in Portuguese, so it might not be American.

Was this an animated movie or was it stop motion animation with puppets?

Good question. My guess is stop motion cuz I remember it being peculiar. Maybe that's why my subconscious is oscillating between "cartoon" and "3d animation".

I believe you are looking for Mad Monster Party from 1967.
According to Imdb

On the Isle of Evil, Baron Boris von Frankenstein reveals his imminent retirement and that he has refined the secret of total destruction, only to be upset when the other monsters try to steal the secret and kill his nephew, Felix Flanken

The only robots are the Baron's assistant Francesca (redhead not a blonde) and the Baron's nephew.
There is a giant gorilla at the end and his appearance causes the Baron to destroy the island. The nephew and Francesca escape in a small boat and when she confesses her love for him but reveals she is a robot. He responds saying

"None of us are perfect {click} perfect {click} perfect.

You can watch the movie at The Internet Archive

Yes YES!!! MWAHAHAHAH! Thank you thank you thank you! My best use of the internet ever :D
